# Soft delete in laravel and model binding

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I have applied a soft delete as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting) for Laravel 5.2. I have one [get] route and another [delete] route:

```
Route::get('profile/{id}/delete', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@delete');
Route::delete('profile/{id}', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@destroy');
```

The controller methods as following:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $profile = Profile::with('contract.division')->withTrashed()->where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('pages.profiles.delete', compact('profile'));
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $profile = Profile::withTrashed()->find($id);

    $profile->delete();

    return redirect('employees/list');
}
```

With this code when I try with non-trashed id I got the content. If I tried with trashed ID I got the following error:

No query results for model [App\Profile]. (View: \xyz\xyz\xyz\resources\views\pages\profiles\delete.blade.php)

1. Despite the error means that there is no query results when I dd($profile) in the delete method I got the full model with relations. So what is going wrong?!
2. When type hinted the profile function delete(Profile $id) I got 404 for trashed model, how exactly I should fix the routes to have the profile ready withTrashed() ?

Comment: Did you add the `use SoftDeletes;` trait to your `Profile.php` model? It might be looking. Also try using `$profile->destroy($id);` instead

Comment: yes I added the trait and my problem is with the error of the first route when user get the form of confirmation of deleting or restoring. Assuming the current model is deleted and I want to restore it so I need to get that model info for restoration.

Answer (score 0):

type hinting trashed model would give you 404, as when you eloquent for trashed models you must specify `withTrashed()`

if you only want to trash in you system you can try

```
if(!$profile->trashed()){
    $profile->delete();
}
```

Comment: 404 is a problem when type hinting the model in the method but what about the error when trashed model received? how I solve the No query results issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found is use suffix or prefix on bind name.

Example:

```php
$controllerPath = 'UsersController';
$routeName = 'users';
$routeBindNameTrashed = "user_trashed";
Route::bind($routeBindNameTrashed, function($userId) use () {
  return App\User::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($userId);
});

Route::put("$routeName/{{$routeBindNameTrashed}}/restore", "{$controllerPath}@restore")->name("{$routeName}.restore");
Route::delete("$routeName/{{$routeBindNameTrashed}}/force", "{$controllerPath}@forceDelete")->name("{$routeName}.force-delete");
```

My real example

[image: softdelete laravel model binding]

Complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62143846/9813428